# What can I do to get my `138a:0094` fingerprint scanner working?

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader

I've tried fprint and fingerprint-gui but neither work.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am also keep looking for this driver. Please followup with below thread. I hope this will help us to get it out. [https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94536](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94536)

Comment: For anyone else who is looking, there is now an active community of people trying to reverse engineer this driver: https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90

Comment: I have the same problem, my laptop is Lenovo yoga 910, still waiting for the drive to be released

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and have done too many searches to find the solution.

**The direct answer:** Unfortunately, until **now** there is no driver for our fingerPrint hardware model (ID: 138a:0094).

But, there is a group of Git developers, they try to do reverse engineering for this and some other fingerprint models. You can check the following link to get updates:

https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90

Good luck,